# Naming the extents of a piece of Earth

Tags: terminology, geography

To a first approximation, Norway would fit in a bounding box of 500x1600x3 km, where 500 km is east-west, 1600 is north-south, and 3 km is up-down. What do you call the extents in each of these dimensions, that is, is Norway 1600 km long wide tall high etc.

```
struct dimensions
{
    float X;  /*< Extent in east-west direction */
    float Y;  /*< Extent in north-south direction */
    float Z;  /*< Extent in elevation direction */
};
```

What to call X, Y, and Z in this case, without having to use an overly long name.

Comment: By 3km do you mean the difference between the highest and lowest altitude? Also: this isn't a box, since the Earth isn't flat, no?

Comment: Interesting. I'm only used to hearing 'lying between the lines of latitude X and Y' etc.

Comment: @alphabet Sure the earth is not flat, and norway is probably a bad example because of this. But you get the idea. Turkey would be better since it covers fewer latitudes, and also aligns pretty will with north-south, west-east. But you get the idea.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is now explicitly about naming variables, which we do not do. Just use X Y and Z, or length/breadth/height or whatever. (If you can make this question so it is not about variables and follow our [word-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-request/info) guidelines, it can probably be reopened.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call these measurements the *[dimensions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dimensions)* or *[extent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extent)* of the [bounding volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume).

Edit: If placed on the planet you can then refer to the "*[longitudinal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/longitudinal)*" and "*[latitudinal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latitudinal)*" lengths and "*depth*" or "*height*".

Comment: I am asking for the individual measurements.

Comment: Question: Does longitudal or latidudal be measured in degrees? I have a "center latidude" to use for scaling if that would be the case.

Comment: Technically yes but you can use length when using the adjectives just to denote directions. For angular measurements you can use "*polar*" and "*azimuthal*". There is more information in the Wikipedia article for spherical coordinate systems.